# Why IIS web site not working when adding Site name

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-6

I created an **Asp.net** website with the **4.5 framework**, it works fine in **Visual studio** with sitename (http://localhost:8080/Mywebsite/Default.aspx) but it is not at the IIS level after deployment.
This is how it is deployed:

[Deployment picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5trAB.png)

When we try to consult the application with the **URL** http://localhost:8080/Mywebsite/Default.aspx, we receive an error message.

An error has occurred in the error page: http://localhost:8080/Mywebsite/Default.aspx: The file 'Mywebsite/Default.aspx' does not exist.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for the one who will encounter the same situation:

after creating the website in **IIS**, we create a folder with the name **Mywebsite1** under the directory **C:\initpub\Mywebsite1** to have at the end **C:\initpub\Mywebsite1\Mywebsite1**, after we return to **IIS** and we create an application under the website initially created and we give it a name like **Mywebsite1** for my case.

In this way, we can access our website with the url http://localhost:8080/Mywebsite/Default.aspx

[Deployment Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH5Fa.png)

Comment: You'd better add links to the official documentation like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis